# Unexpected token '<' in THREEJS DRACOLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf, parceljs

I am currently working on a website where a 3D scene needs to be displayed.
With the 3D artist working with me we need to compress our 3D scene in order to get a faster loading time and a smaller charge on our server, we did through the in-built blender compression tool.

My code was working well until we tried to put the new model and include DRACOLoader, it now returns  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`.

I tried to check if the 3D scene might be the cause of it but it loads perfectly fine in any online GLTF viewers.

if I keep the exact same code with the previous uncompressed object it displays fine.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js'


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

//SETUP CAMERA
var _camera;
_camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);        
_camera.position.set(-10, 5, 15);
_camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
_camera.lookAt(_camera.target);


var _controls = new OrbitControls( _camera, renderer.domElement );
_controls.target = _camera.target;


//CD OBJ PATH + LOADER
const objURL= new URL('../../static/sceneCOMP.gltf', import.meta.url)
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('three/examples/js/libs/draco/gltf'); // use a full url path
loader.setDRACOLoader( dracoLoader );

var model;

//LOAD OBJ
loader.load( objURL.href, function ( glb ) {
    model = glb.scene;
    scene.add( model );
    
}, undefined, function ( error ) {

    console.error( error );

} );

// SETUP LIGHT
        const light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040, 1 ); // soft white light
        scene.add( light )
        
        //DIRECTIONAL LIGHT + SHADOW
        const light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.3 );
        light2.position.set( 0, 10, -5); //default; light shining from top
        light2.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        scene.add( light2 );

//ANIMATE WITH OBJ ANIMATION (MIXER + DELTA)
function animate(time){
    renderer.render(scene, _camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});
```

I'm still suspecting the 3D model to be faulty because without changing the code i can still load uncompressed scene but it still loads fine on any online GLTF viewer. I looked into a lot of example but cannot find a way to make it work.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Most likely one of your URLs is wrong; such an error usually occurs, when a certain data type was expected, but the server responded with an error document instead (which usually starts with either a doctype or `<html>`, and therefor the first character in that response would already be an "unexpected `<`" then.)

Comment: There's a comment in the code: "_use a full url path_", it looks like a path with protocol and domain parts is expected, where as you've passed a plain relative path instead.

Comment: I was suspecting an issue with this url actually but somehow i cannot find anywhere a cdn still online for the draco decoder. they all just return 404